# onClickListener calls TextWatcher: Illegal forward reference

Tags: java, android, onclick, textwatcher

I'm working on Radio Buttons and I want each `RadioButton` to re-call the `TextWatcher` in every `onClick` to update my `TextView` but it doesn't work.

all of this code is inside a `Fragment` and I got only **one Activity**

**RadioButton:**

```
View.OnClickListener radio1Clicked = v ->{
        radioButton1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher); //error under textWatcher : Illegal forward reference
        //More Operations Running here ... };

View.OnClickListener radio2Clicked = v ->{ 
        radioButton2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)};//error under textWatcher: Illegal forward reference
        //More Operations Running here ... };

View.OnClickListener radio3Clicked = v ->{ 
        radioButton2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)};//error under textWatcher: Illegal forward reference
        //More Operations Running here ... };
```

**Text Watcher:**

```
    TextWatcher textWatcher= new TextWatcher(){
        //Declarations and other stuff
                // RadioButton1
                if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
                    basePrintable = 50;
                    calculatePcs = (int) (50 / sqIn);
                    iPieces.setText(String.valueOf(calculatePcs ));
                    if (!checker)//check Switch {
                        iPriceOut.setText("150.0");
                    } else if (checker) //re-check Switch{
                        iPriceOut.setText("50.0");
                    }
                }
                // RadioButton1
                if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
                    basePrintable = 50;
                    calculatePcs = (int) (50 / sqIn);
                    iPieces.setText(String.valueOf(calculatePcs ));
                    if (!checker)//check Switch {
                        iPriceOut.setText("150.0");
                    } else if (checker) //re-check Switch{
                        iPriceOut.setText("50.0");
                    }
                }
                // RadioButton2
                if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {...}
                // RadioButton3
                if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {...}


     basePcs = Integer.parseInt(iPieces.getText().toString());
                baseSheet = 
     Integer.parseInt(iShit.getText().toString());
                basePrice = 
     Double.parseDouble(iPriceOut.getText().toString());
    }
```

I know it could be called cause I'm already doing it here: (and it works)

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton switchInput, boolean isChecked) {
        switchInput.addTextChangedListener(size);
        if (!isChecked) {
            switchInput.setText("...");
            radioButton1.setText("...");
            radioButton2.setText("...");
            radioButton3.setText("...");
        } else {
            switchInput.setText("...");
            radioButton1.setText("...");
            radioButton2.setText("...");
            radioButton3.setText("...");
        }
    }
```

I'm a complete noob and only following along Tutorials and stitching this app for myself. this is the last problem I have to solve cause everything else is more or less done.

Thanks for the Help

Comment: I can see a couple of issues. First, change the name of the onClickListeners to something different than radioButton1,2,3, since that's a name you're already using for the radio buttons. Secondly, where are you instantiating the textWatcher? Seeing more context would help.

Comment: @GuidoC. thanks for the reply and sorry for the confusion,
I already edited the onClickListeners here, it was fine in the code...

Comment: Ok good! But still, we need to know exactly where the text watcher is instantiated. If you only declare `TextWatcher textWatcher;` but you're instantiating it elsewhere, it might throw the exception you're seeing.

Comment: I Hope im answering your 2nd question properly:
There are loads of computation inside my TextWatcher it's Checking wheter my swith is checked or not, what radio button is selected, and checking the editTexts for values input by User, all of this are being checked inside the TextWatcher, after all the checks i will display the "Price" of all checked data.
if there are changes from user input, anywhere he update, I want my TextView to update altogether

Comment: Not really an issue with what the TextWatcher does. It is more an issue of how it is created, so to say. Would you mind sharing the whole class file, or at least the parts where there are the radio buttons, on click listener and text watcher? Can't help you with the current code we have, I can only guess where the issue is.

Comment: I attached the whole class (Unedited) here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LppAH0CVjCoxxHUMJ31QokUfUzQ4lNpu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok thanks. Try moving `TextWatcher size = new TextWatcher() { .... ` with all the code inside, and move it before the `onCreateView` method.

Comment: Great! the error is now gone but the line `iOpt1.addTextChangedListener(size);` under the radio buttons is being Skipped

Comment: Same thing, move the listeners' declarations before onCreateView. In Java you can't really access a variable before defining it, vertically in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to update or refresh the `TextWatcher` by re-assigning it's own content back to an `EditText` it was injected on, this will cause an update and will run the `TextWatcher` since basically it has been updated.

```
 View.OnClickListener o1 = v ->{
        if (iOpt1.isChecked()) {
            iOpt2.setChecked(false);
            iOpt3.setChecked(false);
        }
        iOpt1.setChecked(true);

        //SOLUTION: save the value on where the **TextWatcher** is injected then re-assign the same value you saved

        refesher = iLength.getText().toString();
        iLength.setText(refesher);

        //This will cause an update to the **TextWatcher** and will run the code again

    };

TextWatcher size = new TextWatcher() {...}
```

**Here's more Context**

```
public class PrintFragment extends Fragment{

EditText iLength, iHeight;
RadioButton iOpt1, iOpt2, iOpt3;
String refresher;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inflate

    iLength = V.findViewById(R.id.length);
        iHeight = V.findViewById(R.id.height);
        iOpt1 = V.findViewById(R.id.opt1);
        iOpt2 = V.findViewById(R.id.opt2);
        iOpt3 = V.findViewById(R.id.opt3);
        

        iLength.addTextChangedListener(size);
        iHeight.addTextChangedListener(size);
        iOpt1.setOnClickListener(o1);
        iOpt2.setOnClickListener(o2);
        iOpt3.setOnClickListener(o3);
     return;
     }

 View.OnClickListener o1 = v ->{
        if (iOpt1.isChecked()) {
            iOpt2.setChecked(false);
            iOpt3.setChecked(false);
        }
        iOpt1.setChecked(true);
        refesher = iLength.getText().toString();
        iLength.setText(refesher);
    };

TextWatcher size = new TextWatcher() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you can't reference the object that was clicked inside, instead use the view that is passed

```
View.OnClickListener o1 = v ->{
        iOpt1.addTextChangedListener(size); //error: Illegal Forward Reference
        if (iOpt1.isChecked()) {
            iOpt2.setChecked(false);
            iOpt3.setChecked(false);
        }
        iOpt1.setChecked(true);
    };
```

change to

```
View.OnClickListener o1 = v ->{
        v.addTextChangedListener(size); <--change here //error: Illegal Forward Reference
        if (v.isChecked()) { <--change here
            iOpt2.setChecked(false);
            iOpt3.setChecked(false);
        }
        v.setChecked(true);<--change here
    };
```

using v as the view was clicked

Comment: I tried it, the `addTextChangedListener` turns red with Cannot resolve method `addTextChangedListener` in `View'

Comment: You could cast it